# What is _KBSE (Keyboard Sense) signal in CDTV and what is it used for

Tags: keyboards, amiga-cdtv

I just managed to unmod CDTV keyboard (swapped wires for CD32) with community's help, but the original wire was gone, so I'm left without _KBSE signal connected. It seems the system doesn't mind.

What is the purpose of Keyboard Sense in this (and other) system(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keyboard sense is simply so the CDTV can detect if a keyboard is attached. The keyboard is an optional feature.

After all, the CDTV is a game console. and games should be plug and play. Having to go thru various setup options, eventually every time playing is not really a great idea. By enabling games to detect keyboard presence they can enable and show options for it, otherwise hidden.